# Renew Intent of an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have a problem getting a URI from the intent in my activity.

this is the code in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.Library"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyzandroid"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyzandroid"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyzandroid"
                android:scheme="content" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyzandroid"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The Problem is that I get in my main activtity only the intent when my activity was first started: This means, if for example, a link is clicked with the ending .xyzandroid, my activity starts an i get the URI. But is my activity started from the launcher, i cant get the URI if someone clicks afterward a link in the browser.

How can I fix this problem? Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435396/renew-intent-of-an-activity/10447014#comment13469934_10435396) is right, you just have to override.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    setIntent(intent);
}
```